# Does the Reddit lens work with 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, lenses

I've seen that I can install a lens for Reddit, but it was for Ubuntu 11.04. How is it working on Ubuntu 11.10?

Answer (score 3):

The Reddit Lens has been updated for Ubuntu 11.10 and may be installed as follows:

In a terminal, type the following commands:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:markjtully/ppa 
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install unity-reddit-lens
```

Then log out and log back in to activate the lens.